# Jint with monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, jint

I just wanted to know if Jint (Javascript Interpreter for .NET) works on MonoTouch. I have a project on MonoDevelop where I use the Jint library and I just wanted to figure out if I can use it with MonoTouch.
Is there any tutorial that I can look into on how to use it?

Comment: Won't this break the AppStore Licencing? You can't have an App that is itself programmable.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. According to MonoTouch I cannot have a dynamic code generetion

Comment: It wont break the AppStore licensing, the requirement was updated to say that you can use scripting languages, as long as you do not download extra code that was not initially in the original distribution of your code.    And if you charge for features, then you must use their billing system, so no new code in exchange for money being paid elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks!!! I've been reading your code examples and they are good!

Comment: Please try with the new version which is a PCL https://github.com/sebastienros/jint https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint Announcement:
https://jint.codeplex.com/discussions/536901

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is possible, but with some modifications to Jint.

[This](http://jint.codeplex.com/discussions/247783) describes what other people have had to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace all the calls to reflection.emit with pure reflection in the file ProxyHelper.cs, if you want to keep the interaction between the C# and JavaScript world.

If you do not need the interaction, you could just comment the internal of the methods.

Regular expression cannot be compiled.